# tcp route was working, now is not

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, splunk, nmap

Running CentOS 6.7 on several VM's, Friday ran a test that sent data from machine 1 to machine 2, successful test. Today, (no changes on either end that anybody will admit to) can't repeat the test, the python script that sends the data gives me a traceback that says 'no route to host.' Can ping both ways (1-2, 2-1, can ssh both ways, nmap from 1 to 2 doesn't show the port I sent to on Friday, nmap on 2 to 127.0.0.1 shows port is open. Of the 12 machines on this network, none can send data to this machine on this port, where all could before. No changes in sending script, no changes in vm network (that I am aware of), as I said, theoretically no changes anywhere, but obviously something changed. If it matters, machine 2 is running Splunk 6.3.1 with a modular input that receives the data over port 2008, worked great until today. Disabled and re-enabled the modular input, restarted Splunk.

Not really sure where to look next.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Did you try restarting the program and rebooting the system? If you ran a regular nmap scan, it likely wont show up because port 2008 isn't scanned by default. Be sure to check your iptables as well.

Comment: Restarted the program, rebooted the machine, no joy, iptables was one of the first things I checked. nmap was run with the -p flag, specifically looking for 2008. This is becoming a real conundrum.